# Save parameters into LocalStorage and Redirect React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, routes, react-router

I making a web application. When backend processing data and redirecting to the client with URL as:

```
http://localhost:3000/signinsuccess?username=sample&token=1234567890#
```

I need to route this URL to a component named `mainPage`, get all the params, then save to LocalStorage. What should I do now?

In the client, I made a Route outside of myApp as:

```
  <Router history={history}>
    <Switch>
      <Route
        component={mainPage}
        path="/signinsuccess"
      />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
```

Comment: write saving logic inside your `mainPage` component `componentDidMount`

Comment: where is your main page? Try posting more code. This isn't enough to understand the whole scope of the problem. :)

Comment: In your `mainPage` component, go ahead and use that `local storage`.

Comment: Tks. I'm using React Hook, this code worked for me:
useEffect(() => {
    var qs = require('qs');
    const queryParams = qs.parse(location.href.split("?")[1], { ignoreQueryPrefix: true });
    localStorage.setItem("authorize_token", authorization);
....
  });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some couples of work need to be done to achieve it:

1. In the componentDidMount you need to parse the url parameter to retrieve parameter value. You can use this small library to parse the url: https://github.com/ljharb/qs?fireglass_rsn=true
2. Save url parameter to local storage.

The code can look like this:

In your mainPage component:

if your component is class component

```
componentDidMount(){

  const queryParams  = qs.parse(location.search, { ignoreQueryPrefix: true })
  //then save expected query param to local storage
  storage.setItem("token", queryPrams.token);
}
```

if your mainPage component is functional component can use hooks

```
//useLocation is a hook can be imported from react-router
const location = useLocation();
React.useEffect(()=>{
  const queryParams = qs.parse(location.search, { ignoreQueryPrefix: true })
  storage.setItem("token", queryPrams.token);

},[])
```

Comment: Tks. It's still helpful. But in my case, location.search is not return wrong data.
For ex:

location.href: http://localhost:3000/#/signinsuccess?abc=123&xyz=456#

location.search is empty


I have to split from href then pass into qs.parse